# Why will php-fpm not start?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have setup an AWS EC2 instance and installed the following:

```
httpd24 php71 php71-fpm php71-mysqlnd mod24_ssl fcgi mod24_fcgid
```

I am wanting to run apache 2.4, php 7.1 and php-fpm. In the below error I am also not understanding what 'nginx' is trying to do, I didn't think I had installed anything to run on nginx, if I am running apache.

```
ERROR: [pool www] cannot get uid for user 'nginx': Success (0)
```

In php-fpm.conf, uncommented I have this

```
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm-7.1.pid
```

In my php-fpm.conf I do not see

```
user = apache
group = apache
```

But I do see them in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

Can somebody please help me sort this out.

Thank You

Comment: this belongs on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved found in the /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf, I found this line.

```
listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
```

Solution - change to

```
listen.acl_users = apache
```